# Getting status before response body

Tags: go

Scenario is filtering records from high volume database 5,000 records from 100,000 records in structured database.

Problem is getting early status: **status ok** in postman or in frontend (browser) and delayed in body response.

```
len(finData) == 0 {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, bson.M{"message": "No data avaialble ", "success": true, "data_source": "data source", "Data": data})
    } else { return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, bson.M{"message": "Data retrieved ", "success": true, "data_source": "data source", "Data": data, "Total Count": count})
}
```

While debugging using vscode debugger I could see data flowing.

Is it because loading 5000 records?

[image: Please check this image for reference]

Comment: The HTTP response is written to the network in the following order: status, headers, body.  The status is always read before the body.  Describe in more detail the problem you are having.

Comment: What about the case when there's no data? Is there a delay in seeing message?

Comment: @DeepakSah I am getting instant response with status and resp body 
{
    "Data": [],
    "data_source": "data source",
    "message": "No data avaialble ",
}

Comment: @CeriseLimón I could see Transfer-Encoding is chunked will that be a reason  ?

Comment: Chunked encoding does not change the order of status/header/body.  Describe the problem in more detail.  What happens and how does that compare to what you expect?

Comment: @CeriseLimón when i hosted my service in local it was performing well, I could see that instant response by the endpoints in postman .


When i hosted my golang service in dev environment (Application) and connected to db ( diff env - DB ) 
I could see the status code comes early and after 5-6 seconds response body is loaded